# Remove parent node altogether if the child is duplicate with other parents' child using xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Input xml- 
Parent node Block re-occurs thrice. I need to remove the duplicate nodes altogether, even if it occurs more than 7 times in the same xml without creating a new xml

```
<Blocks>
  <Block>
     <Name>Table</Name>
     <Value>wood</Value>
  </Block>
  <Block>
     <Name>Chair</Name>
     <Value>Plastic</Value>
  </Block>
  <Block>
     <Name>Table</Name>
     <Value>wood</Value>
  </Block>
  <Block>
     <Name>Table</Name>
     <Value>wood</Value>
  </Block>
</Blocks>
```

after execution:

```
<Blocks>
  <Block>
     <Name>Table</Name>
     <Value>wood</Value>
  </Block>
  <Block>
     <Name>Chair</Name>
     <Value>Plastic</Value>
  </Block>
</Blocks>
```

Comment: Well, do you know it is `Block` elements with those two child `Name` and `Value` elements you need to eliminate? Then it is an easy grouping problem you can solve with `xsl:for-each-group select="Block" composite="yes" group-by="Name, Value"` in XSLT 3 or `xsl:for-each-group select="Block" group-by="concat(Name, '|', Value)"` in XSLT 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <xsl:template match="Blocks">
 <Blocks>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="Block" group-by="Name">
     <xsl:sequence select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </Blocks>
```

xslt 2.0